# From file to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to put a file in a dictionary.
The file is like this:

```
1 some something something
2 go goforit doit 
17 non so
```

I am trying something like this but is doesnt work:

```
def filetodic():
 d={}
 with open("file.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
   key  = line.split()
 return d
print filetodic()
```

**EDIT:** The key for every field in the dictionary needs to be the number that appears to be the first element in each line in the file.

Comment: What you want the dictionary to look like?

Comment: so, `{1:"some", 2:"go"}`, or `{1:"some something something", 2:"go goforit doit"}`, or `{1:("some", "something", "something"), 2:("go", "goforit", "doit")}`, or something else entirely? You still are not being very clear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def filetodic():
    d={}
    f = open("file.txt")
    for line in f:
        key  = line.split()
        d[key[0]]= ' '.join(key[1:])
    return d

print filetodic()
```

Comment: `d[key[0]]= ' '.join(key[1:])` can you explain what is the meaning of this line?

Comment: `key = line.split()` will split the line with the whitespace as a delimeter(consecutive whitespaces are counted as a whole 1 whitespace) and return a list with all the words. And `d[key[0]]= ' '.join(key[1:])` will assign the first element of the list as the key of the dictionary and the rest of the list as the value.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want `{1:"some something something", 2:"go goforit doit"}` (as indicated in a comment), try

```
k, v = line.rstrip().split(None, 1)
d[int(k)] = v
```

Note that this preserves spacing in the value itself (e.g. `1 abc  def` becomes `1:'abc  def'` instead of `1:'abc def'`).

Comment: that one has a `\n` in the end of each element

Comment: Can you tell me what is the meaning of each line ?

Comment: First line removes the trailing whitespace (`.rstrip`), then splits the line at most once on whitespace (`split(None, 1)`). The next line converts the key to an int (`int(k)`) and sets the dictionary entry (`d[...] = v`).

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions:

```
rg = re.compile(r'(?P<k>[0-9]+)[ \t]+(?P<v>[A-Za-z\t .]+)')

def filetodic(fileo):
    return {int(k):v.strip() for k,v in [rg.match(line).groups() for line in fileo]}

print filetodic(open("test.txt"))
```